# Error in projNET and DotSpatial projection to EPSG:2950 coordinates

Tags: proj, dotspatial

I need to convert a point from **EPSG:4326** to **EPSG:2950**. But I am consistently getting a wrong result.

On the platform I’m using I can only use the following libraries:

- projNET ([link](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI))
- DotSpatial ([link](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial/))

All the other libraries are not usable for my platforms (SharpProj, ProjNet (for GeoAPI))

This is the point I need to project:

```csharp
lat = 45.5695933
lon = -73.567262
```

This is the result I get from projNET and DotSpatial:

```csharp
X = 299549.937698
Y = 5047744.844475
```

I verified the conversion from multiple sources (OGR, QGIS, epsg.io) and this is the result I would expect:

```csharp
refX = 299550.051922
refY = 5047743.822147
```

As you can see there is a difference of approximately 1 meter:

```csharp
diffX = X - refX = -0.11
diffY = Y - refY = 1.022
```

This is unacceptable for my use case

I tried using different WKT’s definitions. But I still get the same error and never the correct conversion.

- OGC WKT

```csharp
PROJCS["NAD83(CSRS) / MTM zone 8",
    GEOGCS["NAD83(CSRS)",
        DATUM["NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101],
            TOWGS84[-0.991,1.9072,0.5129,-1.25033E-07,-4.6785E-08,-5.6529E-08,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4617"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-73.5],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",304800],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2950"]]
```

- OGR WKT

```csharp
PROJCS["NAD83(CSRS) / MTM zone 8",
    GEOGCS["NAD83(CSRS)",
        DATUM["NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,  
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6140"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4617"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-73.5],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",304800],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2950"]]
```

- ESRI WKT

```csharp
PROJCS["NAD_1983_CSRS_MTM_8",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS",
        DATUM["D_North_American_1983_CSRS",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",304800.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-73.5],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

- Spatial reference

```csharp
PROJCS["NAD83(CSRS) / MTM zone 8",
    GEOGCS["NAD83(CSRS)",
        DATUM["D_North_American_1983_CSRS98",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
        PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
        PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
        PARAMETER["central_meridian",-73.5],
        PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],
        PARAMETER["false_easting",304800],
        PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
        UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

This is the code used for the conversion with DotSpatial:

```csharp
double lat = 45.5695933;
double lon = -73.567262;

double[] xy = new double[2] { lon, lat };
double[] z = new double[1] { 1 };

Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xy, z, ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(4326), ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(2950), 0, 1);
```

What can I do to get an accurate projection from projNET or DotSpatial?

Comment: The definitive EPSG registry definition is https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/2950

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is useful to know. Unfortunately this is the WKT version 2, which is not supported by the above libraries. Do you know if it exists an equivalent definition for Version 1?

Comment: You can get it through their API with: `https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordRefSystem/2950/export/?format=wkt&formatVersion=1`